# Solve $10^{10^z} = 10^{10^x}+10^{10^y}$ for $z$ with floating point accuracy

Tags: exponentiation, floating-point

In the following equation
$$10^{10^z} = 10^{10^x}+10^{10^y}$$
I want to find an algorithm that computes $z$ in a floating point accurate manner given any values of $x$ and $y$ (e.g. $x=y=2000$). The algorithm should thus avoid evaluating $10^x$ or $10^y$ directly otherwise a memory usage error happens. What would be a good method?

I tried looking through the literature but was unable to find anything relevant to this double exponentiation problem.

Comment: Is more detailed information about $x,y$ available? For example: $x \gg y$ or $|x - y| = \mathcal{o}(x)$, ...

Comment: Do you intend to input the number of digits of accuracy, together with the values of $x$ and $y$? Or do you intend to stick with the standards of programming language floating point accuracy? For $x,y \ge 2000$, if you were interested in, say, only $10^{1000}$ digits of accuracy then there is a very simple algorithm: $z = \max\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your interest both. Both $x$ and $y$ can have values from a large range (think 0 to 10^10) so the algorithm should also be valid for that range. I aim to have an algorithm that results in a $z$ with similar floating point accuracy as the inputs $x$ and $y$ (this algorithm will be applied multiple times in sequence so significant accuracy loss is to be avoided). For the limit cases where $x \approx y$ and $x \gg y$ I can simply use easily derivable approximation, however in the transition zone is the main problem.

Comment: Say $x<y:$
$$10^z\ln 10=10^y\ln 10+\ln(1+10^{10^x-10^y})\approx 10^y\ln 10+10^{10^x-10^y}\implies$$
$$z\approx \dfrac{\ln\left(10^y+\dfrac{10^{10^x-10^y}}{\ln 10}\right)}{\ln 10}.$$

If $x,y$ are positive integers, then the "error" term is at most $10^{-90}.$ You can use the actual bounds:
$$\dfrac{x}{1+x}<\ln x <x$$ for small $x$, to get upper and lower bounds as well.

This means that in many occasions, $z$ and $\max{x,y}$ will agree to a good number of digits.

Comment: @dezdichado Thanks that helps a lot in formulating a solution. I think that I can solve this problem with this insight.